# Proper way to add subview to UITableViewCell contentView

Tags: iphone, xcode, uitableview, uiimageview

In my application i need to display multiple images in a UITableView,so i've already searched a lot in the web for the proper way to load large images to UITableViewCells,to be more clearly i'll divide the procedure that my app execute:

1. Download images asynchronous;
2. Save them to NSHomeDirectory();

=> Thins part is working perfectly.

The problem is,how to display the images in the UITableViewCell,i've already tried to add UIImageView's to the cell contentView but the scrolling performance were a bit affected,i've searched on Apple guides and i believe the correct way is adding UIImageView's to the cell and loading the images from NSHomeDirectory(),so:

**What's the best way to customize a UITableViewCell and add the UIImageView's(302x302px) to it?**

Answer (score 2):

To get the best scroll performance, you must draw the content of the UITableViewCell yourself.
Loren Brichter, the author of the Tweetie app (now the official Twitter app), wrote a very famous blog post on this. Sadly, this blog post has been deleted.
[This article](http://ioscodesamples.blogspot.dk/2011/02/daily-done-better.html) may help you, though. It explains the fast scrolling, it has examples and it has a video to a presentation from Loren Brichter.

Basically, what you want to do is to subclass UITableViewCell and override the `drawRect:`method. To show an image, you would do something like the following:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    [myImage drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(10, 10)];
}
```

This way you avoid to layout a lot of subviews.

Comment: Is this still true on the latest hardware/OS?

Comment: To be honest, I don't know if it still applies to the latest OS. I see no reason why it shouldn't. I believe that you will always get the best performance when overriding `-drawRect:`.

Comment: I'm already using drawRect,but is possible to download an image directly from drawRect,i mean request the download procedure from the drawRect?

Comment: @MateusNunes I am not sure. I guess it is. You could take a look at [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage) and use their blocks. I think that would do it. Otherwise you could do it from outside `drawRect:` and then update your cell when the image has been downloaded. I doubt that would be necessary, though.

Comment: You can download your image on a background thread, and then send `-setNeedsDisplay` to your view. When your view redraws it will have the appropriate image available.

Answer (score 2):

I have the same question.
I'm doing the following:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString* CustomCellIdentifier = @"CustomCellIdentifier";

    CustomCell* cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CustomCellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[CustomCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CustomCellIdentifier];
    }

    // add subview to cell
    if (cell.customView == NULL) {
         cell.customView = [[CustomView alloc] initWithFrame:cell.frame];
         [cell.contentView addSubview:cell.customView];
    }

    // bind cell data

    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you need to create a custom cells for UITableView & keep going through following points.

1. set height of each row to 302 pixels as

   ```
   -(CGFloat) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
   ```

   {
              return 302.0;
      }
2. Use following code to create UIImageView at each cell of table
       -(UITableViewCell*) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
       {
               UITableViewCell *cell=[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];

   ```
           const NSInteger IMAGE_VIEW_TAG=1001;

           UIImageView *imageView;

           if(cell==nil)
           {
                   cell=[[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"cell"] autorelease];

                   cell.accessoryType=UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;

                   imageView =[[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 0, 302, 302)] autorelease];
                   imageView.tag=IMAGE_VIEW_TAG;
                   imageView.contentMode=UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
                   [cell.contentView addSubview:imageView];
            }

   imageView=(UIImageView*)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:IMAGE_VIEW_TAG];
   [imageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"];
   return cell;
   ```

   }
3. set number of rows you want to display

   ```
    -(NSInteger) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
    {
             return 5;
    }
   ```
4. dont forget to add TableView delegate and data source , UITableViewDelegate and UITableViewDataSource